# Spring Data MongoDB: Query by class instance

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a Spring Data MongoDB Repository that I want to query with a search criteria defined as an object.

Details:

I have a model class:

```
@Document
public class ModelClass {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    ...
    private String field10;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I also have a MongoRepository to store instances of such class:

```
public interface Repo extends MongoRepository<ModelClass,String> {}
```

I would like to query the repository using instances of ModelClass as search criteria.Such instances may not have values in all fields (some fields may hold **null**). So, in the Repo interface, I need something like:

```
List<ModelClass> findByXXXX(ModelClass criteria);
```

The goal is to query the Repo without the need of writing all the possible combinations of fields.

Comment: Well, the `spring-data` API doesn't have it. The closest thing I can think of is `findByField1AndField2...AndField10` and put the fields which are frequent in your queries and are (or should be) indexed at the begining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For very dynamic queries, Spring Data JPA integrates with [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/). It allows you to define predicates on the fly and execute them as MongoDB queries. The [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl) has details on that.

Comment: Reference documentation link gives a 404, I suppose the corresponding current link is probably https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl